# Cross Compile for the NAO robot / Naoqi OS

Tags: nao-robot

Are there a package manager for naoqi os if you want to add tools to the Linux naoqi-os.
Or are there any instructions howto cross-compile for naoqi os?

Answer (score 1):

The Linux package manager is not open, and there is no root access on most robots.
You can extend the functionalities with the NAOqi [PackageManager](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao-naoqi-2-1/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-framework/naoqi-apis/naoqi-core/packagemanager), and add the libraries you want to use alongside the programs you install on the robot.
You will need to [cross-compile](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/cpp/install_guide.html) the libraries for the robot to do so.